# What is a "table_reference" mentioned in MySQL-docu?

Tags: mysql, reference

The MySQL-documentation keeps mentioning a so called "table_reference". But I'm not sure what **exactly** is a table reference and what's not! Searching the documentation didn't get me any further either..

What I need to know is if a JOIN is a table reference, if an inner SELECT is one and so on. I could simply try but I hope someone has a better resource that keeps track of this stuff!

Example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: If you read the doc page you linked, it links to definitions of table_references, which eventually end up here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

Comment: you're right, i'm a blind fool :c post it as answer so i can accept it!

Comment: @d.hill your not the only blind fool, count me in :)

Comment: `table_reference` = `{db}.{table} as {alias}` or `(t2, t3, t4)` or something even more crazy that ends up in a table format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the doc page you linked, it links to definitions of table_references, which eventually end up here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your link, a table_reference is whatever looks like a table and is named. This includes (at least, that's what hits my mind right now)

- tables
- updateable joins with an alias
- updateable views

Answer (score 0):

In an update statement, a table reference is simply the name of a table.

Try looking at the examples in the documentation. E.g.

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

That's an example where 2 tables are listed in the "table references" section.